# Configuring GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, pull-request, ghprb

I have been trying to set up to GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin for a while now. But when I submit a pull request to my repo, nothing happens when I comment a phrase like 'test this please'. Connections and repo permissions the bot user has seem to show up fine in Jenkins. I tried posting a comment on an issue through Jenkins just to make sure if I have done a correct setup, this throws errors.I have done the basic setup, but obviously there is something missing. Can someone please help me do the setup? 
Some questions that I have are:

- What is the difference between admin and botuser as mentioned in the documentation?
- Does a whitelist user not have to post a comment phrase to trigger the build?(does not work for me either way).

Would appreciate any help. Have been stuck for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration of your pull request builder using the following steps:

1. Go to Github -> repository settings -> webhooks & services and check that there a webhook configured that calls Jenkins on /ghprbhook, content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
2. In the list of events in the Github trigger configuration, make sure that the 'pull request' and 'issue comment'  events are checked.
3. In the Jenkins job configuration, verify that "Use github hooks for build triggering" is checked and make sure that the 'Trigger phrase' is set up correctly. We use `\Qok to test\E`.

Comment: Do I need a webhook if I have Crontab line set?

Comment: No, the webhook configuration disables the crontab line. What's your crontab line?

Is your build service reachable from the internet? In other words, can Github call the pull request builder webhook? If so, have you tried setting up the webhook?

Comment: Triggering of the job is the 2nd step I guess. First of all in the plugin config is not working when I test this "Test adding comment to Pull Request". "Test Permissions to a Repository" returns correct info. But "Test adding comment to Pull Request" fails. And how do I check if Github can call the pull request builder webhook?

Comment: When your build service is accessible from the internet (and not hidden behind a corporate firewall or such), Github should be able to call the pull request trigger.

What's the error message that  "Test adding comment to Pull Request" fails with? Have you checked the Jenkins logs for it?